# Shell script to batch download file using curl(or just send GET request)

Tags: html, batch-file, curl, get

I want to send a GET request(or download HTML) here:

http://expmasters.0fees.us/

The HTML must be:

```
<html>
<head><title>hello worl</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>hello worl</h1></center>
<hr><center>hello world</center>
</body>
</html>
```

But I get only this:

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Batch file:

```
curl http://expmasters.0fees.us
pause
```

So, how can I do this like my browser?

Comment: Sending the user agent seems to work `curl -A "UserAgentString" http://expmasters.0fees.us` so I would guess that the server is checking the user agent...? Try that and it works for me. Although it doesn't give the content you want, but rather some Javascript warning - curl doesn't execute Javascript.

Comment: @samiles, But on the page there is no javascript, may be a hosting adds it...